# Отправлять каждое поле формы AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, форма

Коллеги, привет!

Передо мной стоит такая задача. Есть форма в модальном окне с `n` строк (количество строк может быть разным) т.к форма создается в  динамически. В каждой строке есть скрытый `input` c значением `id` .

Вопрос заключается в том, как мне отправлять каждую строку в обработку на сервер?

Заранее благодарю Вас за потраченное время и полезную информацию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhttp.open("POST", "collector.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
message = "";
for(id = 0; id < количествоСтрок; id++){
    message += "" + источникСтрок(id) + "\n";
}
xhttp.send("msg=" + message);
```

То есть, я бы собрал в цикле все строки в одну длинную строку, поставил между ними разделители (в данном случае `\n`), и заPOSTил в одном параметре.